# Increment number by one using an insert statement SQL

Tags: sql, insert, increment

I am trying to manually add records to a SQL table
However in this table we have a column called Trackseq this column determines how the data is viewed on our CMS system.
The highest TrackSeq will appear first.
I want to manually add a new row but i want the code to check based on CLNTID what the current trackSeq is and add one to it. So if the trackseq of the last record was 10 I want the new record to go in with a trackseq of 11.
Here is my code.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_CommTracking   (    CLNTID,
        TRACKSEQ,
        COMMDATE,
        COMMTIME,
    PRODCODE,
    COMMTYPE,
        EMPLOYEEID,
        COMMDETAILS,
        COMMSTATUS)
VALUES ('0000005566','999',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'BS','Note','0000000786','Testing a manual import','A')
```

Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TRACKSEQ` is a numeric format, you can read the actual highest value and store it in a variable to use in your insert statement.

Please note that, in case of high concurrency, you may want to synchronize this execution in order to avoid duplicate @ts values.
As stated by @Tim Biegeleisen above, an IDENTITY column is best suited for this kind of tasks, but keep in mind that it may leave holes in number sequence in case of DELETE and failed INSERTS.

Eg:

```
DECLARE @ts int; --or whatever numeric datatype it is
SELECT @ts = MAX(TRACKSEQ) + 1 FROM tbl_CommTracking   

INSERT INTO tbl_CommTracking   (
   --...
   TRACKSEQ
   --..
)
VALUES (
   --...
   @ts
   --...
)
```

Comment: Hi LittleSweetSeas The column trackseq is a decimal datatype if i add your solution to my query i get a error meeage 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'

Comment: This worked perfectly i forgot to remove the quotes from my variable in the insert statement.,

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make `TRACKSEQ` an auto increment column.  First drop your current `TRACKSEQ` column, then add it back:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_CommTrackingDROP COLUMN TRACKSEQ;
ALTER TABLE tbl_CommTracking ADD TRACKSEQ INT IDENTITY;
```

Note that typically you would also make `TRACKSEQ` the primary key of the table.  If you don't want to, that's OK, but then you'll have to make sure you can generate your own unique values for the `CLNTID` column.

It isn't entirely clear why you need this; if you just want the latest records, use the date/timestamp column available, which would have been set during insertion.

Comment: Hi Tim I cant alter the table as the sequence is set but the actual application (CMS system) im not sure what would happen if i changed the table and would rather not)

Comment: There is a way to port the existing data over to a new auto increment column.  But before we go down that road, why can't you just use the timestamp to determine which record is the most recent?